# Clear email body except a table

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that saves the email as a pdf and then creates a new mail by attaching this file.
Before saving this email, I need to remove some of the content from email body. I have to leave only the table.

```vb
Sub SaveMessageAsPDF()
     
Dim Selection As Selection
Dim obj As Object
Dim Item As MailItem
     
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Selection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

For Each obj In Selection
 
    Set Item = obj
    
    Dim FSO As Object, TmpFolder As Object
    Dim sName As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set tmpFileName = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    
    sName = Item.Subject
    ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
    tmpFileName = tmpFileName & "\" & sName & ".mht"
    
    Item.SaveAs tmpFileName, olMHTML
    
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=tmpFileName, Visible:=True)
  
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim SpecialPath As String
    Dim strToSaveAs As String
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyDocs = WshShell.SpecialFolders(16)
       
    strToSaveAs = MyDocs & "\" & sName & ".pdf"
 
    ' check for duplicate filenames
    ' if matched, add the current time to the file name
    If FSO.FileExists(strToSaveAs) Then
        sName = sName & Format(Now, "hhmmss")
        strToSaveAs = MyDocs & "\" & sName & ".pdf"
    End If
  
    wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    strToSaveAs, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
    OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
    Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, Item:= _
    wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
             
Next obj
wrdDoc.Close
wrdApp.Quit
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
Set obj = Nothing
Set Selection = Nothing
Set Item = Nothing
  
  
'Create an Outlook object and new mail message
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
        
'Display email and specify To, Subject, etc
With OutlookMail
        
    .Display
    .To = "***@p***.net "
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "zamówienie"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "zamówienie do realizacji"
    .Attachments.Add strToSaveAs
              
    DisplayEmail = True
End With
 
End Sub
```

[email example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK2Eg.jpg)

I tried the split function, but the formatting of the email changes and there is no longer a table, only the content itself.